Item bullet does not appear in very specific cases with beamer
In the minimal code below (compile with latex + dvipdfmx), beamer with dvipdfmx driver in 4-on-1 layout mode does not show rounded item bullets. Is there any way to fix this? Changing either the driver, the layout, or the bullet style seems to work.
\documentclass[dvipdfmx]{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[landscape]

\useinnertheme{rounded}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item item 1
    \item item 2
    \item item 3
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE. Just out of idle curiosity: What's your use case for going the dvipdfmx route?

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/568646/36296 for a detailed explanation. If you want to keep using latex, use dvips and ps2pdf -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY to convert to pdf

I have been happy with it for more than 20 years. When I switched to it, it was doing a much better job than dvipdf. I have no other reason.

@user127306 If you can, I would directly produce a pdf, e.g. with pdflatex or lualatex
